# C: invalid operands to binary > (have ‘float’ and ‘float (*)(float **, long int, long int, short int *)’)

Tags: c

I wrote a very simple code to find max in an array. I cannot figure out what's wrong here...

```
float maxValue(float **ArrayIn, long length, long width, short* result_coor){
    int i,j;
    float maxvalue = ArrayIn[0][0];
    for(i=0;i<length;i++){
        for(j=0;j<width;j++){
            if((ArrayIn[i][j]>maxValue)==1){
                maxValue = ArrayIn[i][j];
                result_coor[0] = i;
                result_coor[1] = j;
            }
        }
    }
    return maxvalue;
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
array_processing.c: In function ‘maxValue’:
array_processing.c:9:20: error: invalid operands to binary > (have ‘float’ and ‘float
(*)(float **, long int,  long int,  short int *)’)
array_processing.c:10:13: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
make: *** [array_processing.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 8):

You managed to outsmart yourself. `maxValue` is the name of the function, and `maxvalue` the name of the local variable. Check your spelling again. And pick better names next time.

Answer (score 2):

It's a typo: use

```
if((ArrayIn[i][j]>maxvalue)==1){
                     ^
                    !!!
```

and

```
    maxvalue = ArrayIn[i][j];
       ^
      !!!
```

You have declared a variable `float maxvalue` (non-capital 'v'), and a function `maxValue(...)` (capital 'v') - so the compiler tries to use the function as second operand of the comparison when you use `maxValue` there.

Keep in mind that C is case significant - so `maxvalue` and `maxValue` are different symbols, but they need to be used properly.

Ideally, try to avoid such issues by choosing better names - for example, use `getMaxValue()` or `calculateMaxValue()` for the function name.

Besides that, `if((ArrayIn[i][j]>maxvalue)==1)` is unnecessarily complex - simply use

```
if(ArrayIn[i][j] > maxvalue)
```

Comment: and also `maxvalue = ArrayIn[i][j];`

Comment: thanks a lot. I have to change the name maxvalue entirely cos that's the same as the function's name...